# grey out submit button until form filled out

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button

I have the following form:

```
 <form action="http://www.tahara.es/contact/subscribe.php" method="post" id="subscribe" name="subscribe">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
      <label>NAME:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="Textbox" id="sub_first_name">
      <label>EMAIL:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="Textbox" id="sub_email">
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Subscribe" />
```

I would like to grey out the `submit` button until both fields in the form have been filled out. I guess jquery would do the trick?

How can I do this, and where should I place the script?

Comment: $('#button').prop('disabled', boolean Are all fields filled out?)...  You can check and change on keyup.. blur.. change.. of input fields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jquery would do that. On the .keyup event have jquery check if both field's lengths are > 0 and change the button to be disabled or not.

```
$('#yourButton').button("disable");​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$('.fields').bind('keyup', function() { 
var nameLength = $("#sub_first_name").length;
var emailLength = $("#sub_email").length;

if (nameLength > 0 && emailLength > 0)
{
   $('#yourButton').button("enable");​​​​​​​​​​​​​
}

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner of javascript, a better option would be

Add **HTML** as follows

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
   First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now add `validateForm()` as

```
function validateForm() {
   // Validate all fields in the form
   return true; // if all form entries are valid. else return false
}
```

**Note:** This will not grey-out the submit button. But in this case submit will work only if all the entries are valid.