# How to conditionally prevent form submission if no data has been entered into the text fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I have this form:

```
<form name="searchForm" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="keywords" name="keywords"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="searchButton" name="searchButton" value="search">Search</button>    
</form>
```

I want to make sure that this form is never submitted unless the text field contains at least one character in it. How do I go forward with this?

Comment: there are lots of tutorials on the web regarding javascript form validation... start there

Answer (score -1):

I would grey out the submit button. Here's a pervious post about it:

[grey out submit button until form filled out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614761/grey-out-submit-button-until-form-filled-out)